# Why automatically omits repeated values when making the conversion?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dictionary :

```
dict_1={'AB':50,'ACC':20,'CEKK':75,'AB':25,'CEKK':75,'BBA':58,'BBA':58 }
```

When I turn it into a df:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=list(dict_1.values()),index=list(dict_1.keys()),columns=['number'])
```

It only provides each key from the dictionary once.

```
            number
 ACC         20
  AB         25
CEKK         75
 BBA         58
```

The desired output would be the df with all the values including repeated ones.

```
            number
 ACC         20
  AB         25
CEKK         75
 BBA         58
  AB         50
CEKK         75
 BBA         58
```

Is there a feasible way I could make the dataframe to include the repeated values without stating the values for the data and index explicitely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python dictionary eliminates all duplicates in keys **before** it gets to Pandas.

```
In [466]: dict_1={'AB':50,'ACC':20,'CEKK':75,'AB':25,'CEKK':75,'BBA':58,'BBA':58 }

In [467]: dict_1
Out[467]: {'AB': 25, 'ACC': 20, 'BBA': 58, 'CEKK': 75}
```

Workaround:

```
In [465]: pd.DataFrame({'number':[20, 25, 75, 58, 50, 75, 58]}, 
                       index=['ACC', 'AB', 'CEKK', 'BBA', 'AB', 'CEKK', 'BBA'])
Out[465]:
      number
ACC       20
AB        25
CEKK      75
BBA       58
AB        50
CEKK      75
BBA       58
```

**UPDATE:** that's what is happening to the dictionary with duplicated keys:

```
In [79]: print({'AB':50,'ACC':20,'CEKK':75,'AB':25,'CEKK':75,'BBA':58,'BBA':58 })
{'AB': 25, 'ACC': 20, 'CEKK': 75, 'BBA': 58}
```

**exactly the same** will happen when you pass it to `pd.DataFrame()` constructor. So `pd.DataFrame()` will receive a dictionary **without** duplicates.

Comment: thank u Max for the explanation, however is there any feasible way to generate the df without explicitly stating the values for the data and the index?

Comment: @ge00rge, there are tons of ways - loading form CSV,DB,JSON,HDF5,numpy array,etc. ;-) It depends on your input data...

Comment: Thank u max however there seems something I am missing , in the example i provided when converting the dict to  df would be as loading a json isn't it?

Comment: @ge00rge, not exactly - AFAIK the only way to load JSON to Pandas is to load it to Python dictionary first. And Python dictionaries do __NOT__ allow duplicates in keys (see example in my answer - duplicated keys will be ignored). So you can use any other method except using dictionary

Comment: my problem is tough then given that my input comes in the form provided in the example ..

Comment: @ge00rge, are you sure your input data is in exactly the same format? This looks to me like a huge design bug...

Comment: From your experience  (surely way longer than mines ) do you find any problem from your point of view? Couldn't I actually recieve a json with that format (repeating values I mean)?

Comment: If you absolutely must deal with JSON with repeated keys, you'll need to change how you're loading the JSON. The `object_pairs_hook` argument to `json.loads` would be useful in this case. It doesn't sound like you're clear on the difference between dicts and JSON, though, and I'm not convinced you actually need to parse JSON at all, let alone with repeated keys.

Comment: @user2357112  you are right, thank you for your feedback, I'll have to give it a turn